# Why do my erasers get very soft?

Tags: office-supplies

I’ve been able to find a lot about fixing hardened erasers but I usually have the opposite problem, they get too soft. Sometimes chunks come off, sometimes it’s like string cheese. What can I do to prevent that?

Comment: That is exactly how a good eraser should behave. As you use it, the surface balls up (strings) and presents a clean face of the eraser. That means they don't smudge the paper with previous pencil lead left on the eraser. If the eraser is hard and abrasive, it wears away the paper, instead of the pencil marks. Erasers are extremely cheap, and it is rare for me to actually wear one out anyway.

Comment: Don't press so hard on them as you erase?

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok that’s good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "get too soft" you mean the eraser is becoming somewhat denatured to a more gooey state, I'd look for a substance in your environment that might be commonly getting on your eraser, such as perhaps hand lotion, air freshener spray particles, specially treated paper, etc., that could be interacting with the eraser's physical structure somehow. Same thing if large chunks come off easily and often, as that might indicate some additional agent changing the chemical structure of the eraser.

Otherwise, I agree that this is how a good eraser should behave. If it's not gooey such that you could slightly reshape it by hand, and you're just seeing some tiny bits of eraser forming into strings and bits as you use it, that is probably just a good eraser functioning as it should.

Comment: Yeah it’s not gooey, it just falls apart over time. All I know is my sister can have the same erasers for years while mine last like 1

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd. Are you working around some form of solvent that would damage the rubber in some way? I'd recommend [buying pencils without erasers](https://unsharpen.com/pencils-without-erasers/) and then having a separate eraser that you keep apart from your art supplies or anything else that might be affecting the rubber of eraser. You can also get tougher erasers that are less prone to being damaged but similar chemicals, like a kneading eraser.

Comment: No just a normal desk. And this doesn’t happen with my pencil erasers or those cap erasers you put on the pencil, it only happens to the bigger ones. But I’ll look into kneading erasers, thanks for that tip